# jQuery event "change" not working when checking out if a selector has a class, need help choosing proper event

Tags: jquery

So I'm working with a jQuery sliding tabs code, and I need other tabs to take on a class when a different tab is selected. This is what I've written:

```
$(document).change(function() {
  if ($('#tab_5').hasClass('st_tab_active')) {
      $('#tab_4').addClass('st_tab_active2');
  }
  else
    {$('#tab_4').removeClass('st_tab_active2');};
} );
```

I'm using `change` but it's not the proper event I can tell, and I'm not sure which is. When clicking on prev and next buttons, `#tab_5` takes on the class `st_tab_active` when it is selected. I need `#tab_4` to take on `st_tab_active2` when this occurs. What is the proper event I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given a list of tabs**

```
<div class="tab active"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".tab").click(function(){
   $(".tab").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

While this example is not an exact duplicate of your situation, it provides several points that are applicable.  First, use a class on the tabs, this gives you easy access to all that tabs at once.  Second, when adding/removing the active class in jQuery simply remove the class from all tabs then apply it to the correct tab.

The script for your situation may be slightly different since it uses a next button.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    var nextElem = $(".active").next();
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    nextElem.addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) , it usually makes it work :

```
$(document).live('change', function() {
  if ($('#tab_5').hasClass('st_tab_active')) {
      $('#tab_4').addClass('st_tab_active2');
  }  else {
    $('#tab_4').removeClass('st_tab_active2');
  }
});
```